# Why Manjaro in VirtualBox should be installed again and again?

Tags: virtualbox, manjaro

I downloaded [Manjaro](https://manjaro.org/) 20.0.1 and installed it in the VirtualBox.

After I restart it, it seems had rollback and will start at the beginning. Again, "Install XXX" showed on the desktop.

I didn't remove CD/DVD device from VirtualBox after install it, if do so, it failed due to can't read file from CD/DVD.

Comment: Which the Manjaro edition? [XFCE, KDE Plasma, Gnome or Architect](https://manjaro.org/download/)?

Comment: @jluizsouzadev KDE

Comment: I got install Manjaro succefully on my machine. Try to download again in this [link](https://manjaro.org/downloads/official/kde/) via torrent as I did. Also tell us which the **OS** and its **version** of the **host machine** and the **VirtuaBox Version**.

Comment: @jluizsouzadev The reason was I used the default boot path when I install it to the disk. Maybe I have to change it to other, but I forgot the options been listed there.

Comment: First of all, check out the **VM settings**. Did you set the VM settings to the **lastest hardware specs**? Which the **OS and Virtualbox versions of host machine**? You don't reply it in my previous comment.